# Take my office computer home, will i have problems logging in?

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain

I need to take my office computer home to do some work. At the office it connects to a domain and i log in with my domain username and password.

When i take it home will i have any trouble logging in as my domain account? I know i will not be able to see mapped drives and stuff.

My other alternative is to log in under the local account but i would rather log in under my domain account.

i am using windows 7

Comment: Does your office have a VPN?  You should still be able to log into your machine from home using the same account (assuming you've logged into it before).

Comment: 1. You shouldn't have any issues logging in with your domain account provided that your IT department hasn't disabled cached logons. 2. Why would you not ask your IT department this question?

Comment: its a small company, no IT dept.

Comment: Then, probably not. :)

Comment: Unplug your computer from the network before you go home, the next morning see if it will let you log in and how useful it is before plugging it back in.

Comment: I advise closing any network shares before taking it home. Opening my laptop up at home and not being connected to my data center makes windows explorer not very happy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not have a problem. Windows will "cache" your login information in the event a domain controller isn't available (like, working from home).

One caution: If your office uses folder redirection you *may* run into problems with your profile and data vanishing.

Comment: Also as option - log in to local system (not domain) providing it is not disabled and he has local account.

Comment: how can i check if theres folder redirection?

Comment: Ask your IT department. Another way to tell would be to disconnect yourself from the network and log in. Windows will complain and log in with a "temporary" profile.

Comment: Also check RSOP info for GPs that force user authentication every login...

Answer (score 1):

If the domain controller at work is serving as your primary DNS server (and you don't have the means to change that), then you won't have internet.